# Partitions and Replications for the Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have read the entire Documentation from the suggested website http://kafka.apache.org/ and did not able to understand the Hardware Requirements

1)I need a clarification on: How many **Partitions and Replication** is Required for collecting minimum **50GB of data per/day** for single topic

2)It is given that the **0000000000000.log** file is able to store up-to 100GB of data. Is it possible to reduce this log file size for reducing the usage of I/O ?

Comment: 1) Is this data comming in a uniform way all day? because if its like that you don't need much to collect 50gb of data per/day
2) you can split the size of a topic by using partitions. Either way I am not sure how much affects kafka the size of that file (I would image not much base on the way that kafka reads information from disk)

Comment: Yes, the Data will in uniform way continuously all over the day. I have checked the Partition concept also by giving the  following command.        bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 3 --topic topic_name. Hear the partitions in the topics are also use to store the same data. can u help on the -nautilus

Comment: Hi syed jameer, was my answer helpful for you?

Comment: hi nautilus working on it trying to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is uniformed ingested during the entire day, that means that you need to ingest something like 600kb per second, all depends on the number of messages that are on those 600kb (according to Jay Creps explanation [here](https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines) you need to calculate something like 22 bytes of overhead per message) (keep in mind that the way you ACK the messages from the producer is also very important)

But you should be able with 1 topic and 1 partition to get this throughput from a producer.

Answer (score -1):

1.Check this link it has the answer to choose #partitions:
   http://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/][1]

2. Yes it is possible to change the maximum size of log file in kafka. You have to set the below mentioned property on each of the brokers and then restart the brokers.

   log.segment.bytes=1073741824

Above line will set the log segment size to 1GB.